# How to access a variable value in shell script file from java code written using netbeans

Tags: java, bash, ubuntu-12.04, netbeans-8

I have created A GUI using java and netbeans IDE, in that java code i have set value of a variable `path` which consists of path of directory such as   `path=/home/usr/jai/newfolder` and i have a shell script file with extension `.sh` in that a command is mentioned which access many files mentioned in newfolder.

My question is how to use `path` variable in that shell script file so that I can access all those files mention in newfolder and execute that file using java code and I know how to execute script file using java code but I am unable to access the variable value in shell script file.

Comment: Pass the value as a parameter to the shell script when you call it.

Comment: ...and access it in your script using `$<n>` where `n` is the position where the variable is located in arguments of the script.

Comment: String cmnd1=path+"/test_script_gui.sh";
                   System.out.println(cmnd1);
                   String cmnd2[]={cmnd1,path};
                   try {
                       Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmnd2);
                       
                   } catch (IOException ex) {
                       Logger.getLogger(filedata.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                   }

Comment: Following is the command given where I have to use variable path in the place of dot signifying current directory   HVite -T 1 -D -A -H ./work_all_3_train_read_test_aprl_20145/hmm$i/macros -H ./work_all_3_train_read_test_aprl_20145/hmm$i/hmmdefs -S ./test_gui.list -C ./analysis_train.conf -I ./test.mlf -i ./work_all_3_train_read_test_aprl_20145/hmm$i/recout_test_gui.mlf -o SWT -w path/wdnet.txt -p -10.0 -s 0 path/dict.txt ./hmmlist.txt     . How to do this??

Comment: This command is used in script file where variable path is to be used. Is the above right for passing the argument path to script file? How to use this argument in script file

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value of environment variable in Java like:

[Ref:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html)

```
import java.util.Map;

public class EnvMap {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
        for (String envName : env.keySet()) {
            System.out.format("%s=%s%n",
                              envName,
                              env.get(envName));
        }
    }
}
```

Then pass that variable value as a command line argument to that shell script.